# Windows-specific issue when rendering WebGL... attribute set to zero?

Tags: javascript, windows, webgl, typed-arrays

I'm running into a hard-to-debug issue using WebGL.  I was implementing a WebGL backend for the CraftyJS game framework.  Everything works absolutely fine on OSX, Linux, and Android, but when a collaborator tested on windows there was an important error -- rotated sprites rendered unrotated!  I was able to replicate this across IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  An example of the type of [vertex program](https://github.com/starwed/Crafty/blob/webgl-pr/src/shaders/color.vert) I'm using, which simply renders a colored rectangle:

```
attribute vec2 aPosition;
attribute vec3 aOrientation;
attribute vec4 aExtra;
attribute vec4 aColor;

varying lowp vec4 vColor;

uniform  vec4 uViewport;

mat4 viewportScale = mat4(2.0 / uViewport.z, 0, 0, 0,    0, -2.0 / uViewport.w, 0,0,    0, 0,1,0,    -1,+1,0,1);
vec4 viewportTranslation = vec4(uViewport.xy, 0, 0);

vec2 entityOrigin = aOrientation.xy;
mat2 entityRotationMatrix = mat2(cos(aOrientation.z), sin(aOrientation.z), -sin(aOrientation.z), cos(aOrientation.z));

void main() {
  vec2 pos = aPosition;
  pos = entityRotationMatrix * (pos - entityOrigin) + entityOrigin ;
  gl_Position = viewportScale * (viewportTranslation + vec4(pos, 1.0/(1.0+exp(aExtra.x) ), 1) );
  vColor = vec4(aColor.rgb*aColor.a*aExtra.y, aColor.a*aExtra.y);
}
```

The problem seems to be related to the `aOrientation` attribute -- it is used to calculate the rotation matrix.  Using Firefox's shader editor, if I manually specify `entityOrigin` and `entityRotationMatrix` then the program will render correctly.  But by default, it renders as if all components of the `aOrientation` attribute were just 0.  Every other aspect of the shader (positioning+dimensions, color, alpha transparency, viewport scale/translation) seems to work fine; it's only behavior which depend on `aOrientation` that is broken, and seemingly only on Windows.

Since I only have infrequent access to a windows machine this is annoyingly hard to debug.  Are there any windows-specific (or hardware/driver specific?) issues that could somehow cause problems setting that one particular attribute?

Comment: vmware fusion, parallels, or virtualbox are your friend ;)

Comment: Sadly, I don't even have a license for windows... in any case, I was kind of hoping someone would see this and just happen to remember a similar circumstance.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, once I actually had time to sit down with a windows machine and experiment -- the compiler was "optimizing" away my attribute on windows.  I guess it makes sense that this might be driver/platform/hardware dependent.

The solution was to place the following lines inside of `main()` instead of outside of it.

```
vec2 entityOrigin = aOrientation.xy;
mat2 entityRotationMatrix = mat2(cos(aOrientation.z), sin(aOrientation.z), -sin(aOrientation.z), cos(aOrientation.z));
```

I guess I don't really understand the difference between code that goes inside of main, and code outside of it.  Something to look into!  :)