# Is it ever reasonable to do computations outside of main in an OpenGL shader?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I have some vertex shader code somewhat like the following (this is a bit of simplified example):

```
attribute vec2 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aColor;

varying lowp vec4 vColor;

uniform  vec4 uViewport;
mat4 viewportScale = mat4(2.0 / uViewport.z, 0, 0, 0,    0, -2.0 / uViewport.w, 0,0,    0, 0,1,0,    -1,+1,0,1);

void main() {
  vec2 pos = aPosition;
  gl_Position = viewportScale * vec4(pos, 0, 1);
  vColor = vec4(aColor.rgb*aColor.a, aColor.a);
}
```

In particular, the `viewportScale` matrix is calculated from the `uViewport` uniform *outside of the main function*.  Using this from a browser (WebGL), it seems to work fine on every machine I've tested on... in particular, the `viewportScale` matrix is correctly updated when I change the `uViewport` variable.  Is there any difference between doing this, and doing the same calculation inside of the main function?  I can't find any examples or discussion related to this.

I ran into a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472077/windows-specific-issue-when-rendering-webgl-attribute-set-to-zero/27555733#27555733) that has made me a bit paranoid about this issue -- at the very least, I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: it'll get optimized anyway

Comment: @ratchetfreak In the related problem I linked to, it did get optimized away.  But with the code in this post, it doesn't (which surprised me after the previous problem); `viewportScale` is updated whenever I update the `uViewport` uniform.  I guess that this is because I directly reference `viewportScale` in main, so the compiler figures out I'm using it.

Comment: any compile log output? (on either)

Comment: No -- is there an easy way to get that from Firefox/Chrome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a legal shader in GLSL ES 1.00, which is the GLSL version that is used with ES 2.0. WebGL shares the same GLSL definition, with some exceptions specified in the WebGL spec. I can't find an exception for this in the WebGL spec, so I believe that the shader is illegal in both ES 2.0 and WebGL.

From the GLSL ES 1.00 spec, section "4.3 Storage Qualifiers" on page 29 (emphasis added):

> Declarations of globals without a storage qualifier, or with just the const qualifier, may include initializers, in which case they will be initialized before the first line of main() is executed.  Such initializers **must  be a constant expression**.

Section "5.10 Constant Expressions" on page 49 defines what a constant expression is. It includes:

> The following may **not** be used in constant expressions:
>
> - **Uniforms**, attributes and varyings.

The expression in your case includes a uniform, which makes it a non-constant expression. It can therefore not be used as the initializer of a global variable.

Comment: I'd totally believe it's illegal, but, why does it then compile and work as I'd intended?

Comment: It's quite common for GLSL compilers to accept shaders that are not spec conformant. Some vendors are more notorious for this than others. I'm not sure if it's just a lack of testing, or if they believe they are doing people a favor by allowing non-conformant shaders to work. It would certainly be risky to tighten up the error checking from release to release, because you could break previously working apps. It's unfortunate if you develop on one platform, and then end up surprised that the same code does not work on other platforms.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what happened to my initial version of the shader (worked fine everywhere but Windows.)  For now I'll assume it could become broken in the future, but I'm kind of curious to see what the compiler is actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem on my Android application.

I defined a variable using an uniform variable outside of main block in a fragment shader.

```
uniform u_rotation;
mat2 rotation = mat2(cos(u_rotation), sin(u_rotation), -sin(u_rotation), cos(u_rotation)); 
void main() {}
```

This fragment shader works well on all Android devices but one Nexus 6. It is weird that I have two Nexus 6, one crashed every time and another one just got wrong result most of the time.

Comment: Link my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002625/androidfragment-shader-crashed-my-application-only-on-nexus-6/30002626#30002626

Comment: Following Reto answer, you have to move the rotation computation inside the main() block.