# [Android]Fragment Shader crashed my application only on Nexus 6

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

One feature from my application was implemented using OpenGL.

Then I found this feature failed working on Nexus 6. I have two Nexus 6 to test. 
One crashed every time I used, but another one just got wrong result most of the time(which means it worked for several times).

I'm trying to figure out why and found that If I don't use a mat2 variable, the application would not crash.

```
uniform u_rotation;
varying highp vec2 v_texcoord;
const vec2 center = vec2(0.5);
mat2 rotation = mat2(cos(u_rotation), sin(u_rotation), -sin(u_rotation), cos(u_rotation)); 
void main() {
vec2 pcoord = center + rotation * (v_texcoord - center);
...
}
```

I had no idea what was happening then.

Comment: Try round cos and sin returned values. Just a guess because everything seems fine.

Comment: Please see the answer below. Not everything is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause is that I defined a variable using an uniform variable outside of the main block.

But I don't know why because:

- Most devices works well
- Only one Nexus 6 would crash

I searched for a while then found the following question and the answer:

[Is it ever reasonable to do computations outside of main in an OpenGL shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076568/is-it-ever-reasonable-to-do-computations-outside-of-main-in-an-opengl-shader/30002417#30002417)

But I'm not totally understand why most devices works well. Maybe someone could explain it for me. Thanks so much!