# OpenGL ES (GLSL ES) global variable in vertex shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, glsles

Maybe this is a trivial question but I didn't find anything on web.
I'm trying to model a particle system where each particle follows the Newton's gravitational law. I have to estimate the trajectory of each particle considering the motion as uniformly accelerated for a small interval.
My question is if it is possible to have global variables (a vec3 for the current position, and a vec3 for the current velocity) such that I can do something like:

```
vec3 p;
vec3 velocity;
void main(){
    float delta_t = 0.1;
    if(//is the first time){
        //Calculate initial parameters
        p = position;
        velocity = vec3(//initial velocity computed);
    }
    vec3 a = //compute actual acceleration vector as -(GM/p^2)*vers(p)
    velocity = velocity + a*delta_t;
    p = p+velocity*delta_t+0.5*a*delta_t*delta_t;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(p, 1.0);

}
```

if I can't do like this, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should read this: [GLSL - Declaring global variables outside of the main function scope](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/61262/18988).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ever reasonable to do computations outside of main in an OpenGL shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076568/is-it-ever-reasonable-to-do-computations-outside-of-main-in-an-opengl-shader)

Comment: @zero298 I'm sorry but this is the first time I use GLSL. I believe that global variables don't exist in GLSL and I don't need uniform as I have to modify them within the vertex shader. Is there a way to achieve this or simply I've to reinvent all because I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want the velocity to persist between shader invocations? If so, you can't just randomly store this in the shader, you would use a render target. You'd render the `velocity + a*delta_t;` part in a separate pass, write the result into a texture and look it up in this shader.

Comment: @pailhead Yes, you're right. I need the velocity to persist. I'll follow your advise, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That global variable will not do what you expect it to do. It will not retain state between different shader invocations.

You need to use a render target for something like this if you want it done entirely on the GPU, or, store this in an attribute which you would update manually and upload to the GPU every frame (don't do this).

The render target should do the `velocity = velocity + a*delta;`

You might also need to "flip flop" two textures (alternate read/write) so you can both read and write to `velocity`. Once you have this texture you would access it in this shader, so instead of computing the velocity, you'd compute the index into the texture. `texture2D( velocitySampler, myIndex )`.